# WinRT, Does the scrollviewer not work in the emulator?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, scrollviewer

I ran into a little bug while creating a scrollable stackpannel. I used the scrollviewer. I have placed the Stackpannel inside the Scrollviewer but I can't scroll using a emulator.. I don't have a windows phone so I cant check it out on an actual phone. Here is my code:

```
 <ScrollViewer Height="979" Margin="0,100,0,-439" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel Height="979" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="268">

        // things inside the stackpannel

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Am I doing something wrong or does the scrollviewer not work in an emulator?

Comment: Never use a StackPanel directly under a ScrollViewer, use a Grid instead.

Comment: Why?? Do you have any explanation or sources to explain?

Comment: Remove Height and Margin values from the `ScrollViewer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of the `ScrollViewer` is the same as the height of the `StackPanel` so there is nothing to scroll (it just falls off the end of the screen). Try using `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"` instead of setting `Height` on the `ScrollViewer` which should help (if not, you have some other problem in your layout ;-) but using a fixed, smaller `Height` for the `ScrollViewer` will solve this immediate problem).